# How to set value from server side code to an asp.net TextBox with TextMode="Date"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am doing a demo application for learning the use of new HTML5 input types (example- Date, email etc as TextMode) introduced in asp.net textbox control.

In my sample page I want to display server side date field data using asp:TextBox with TextMode="Date".

The asp.net code goes as:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtExpenseDate" TextMode="Date" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

The C# backend code goes as

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtExpenseDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```

But while the page loads, the date value does not get displayed in the textbox.

What am I doing wrong?

addendum:
Just realized that since this is HTML5, I must mention browser version. I am on latest Google Chrome Version 33.0.1750.117 m. This displays the field as a calendar to pick the date, thus supports the HTML5 equivalant of TextMode="Date" attribute .

Regards,

Sumit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the below code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.txtExpenseDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        }
```

http://forums.asp.net/t/1856516.aspx?Problem+with+date+textmode+for+textbox+in+vs2012+net+4+5

Comment: Date format "yyyy-MM-dd" is the answer key here, This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

> But while the page loads, the date value does not get displayed in the
>   textbox.

You need to set the value for the `TextBox` control in `Page_Load` event of the Webpage

Try This:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtExpenseDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```

Comment: Yes, yes. I put that in a event handler/ method. I thought this is obvious so I did not wrap that around the code Page_Load in the question. But with even/ function wrapper - it does not work.

Comment: I added the wrapper now in the question for clarity. No success yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your TextMode set as Date 
So you need to convert at exact as date format optionally you can set textmode as date. like below.

```
this.txtExpenseDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
this.txtExpenseDate.TextMode=TextBoxMode.Date;
```