# How to Autofil the TextBox with Current date

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello dear All hope you all are fine and doing well, I am new on .net development i am creating a project which will get the information about the user daily base but the problem is that i want to autofill the date textbox with current date,
Here is my Code behind page_load

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;

namespace StackOver
{
 public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
  protected void Page_Load(object sender,EventArgs e)
  {
   TextBoxStartDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();

   if (!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
    LoadOptionsCardCodeTable();
    LoadOptionsStageSlpNameTable();
   }
  }

  protected void TextBoxStartDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   TextBoxStartDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
  }
 }
}
```

And also here is my aspx.cs code for that textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxStartDate" runat="server" ontextchanged="TextBoxStartDate_TextChanged" Width="150px" Height="16px" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Thanks in Advance its not showing error but current date not showing
kindly help

Comment: What's result of above existing code?

Comment: empty textBox means its not filling the current date in TextBoxStartDate @LeiYang

Comment: try ->
this.TextBoxStartDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

possible duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21952542/how-to-set-value-from-server-side-code-to-an-asp-net-textbox-with-textmode-date

Comment: How you get the value in server side , Without using AutoPostBack="true"

Comment: @ rajeeshmenoth : `runat="server"` is enough to get value in server side

Comment: @un-lucky : I mean textchanged value :)

Comment: I think `ReadOnly="true"` will solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add **AutoPostBack="true"** In Aspx Textbox.

The following code is working fine :

**Code Behind :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBoxStartDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {


    }
}
protected void TextBoxStartDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBoxStartDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
}
```

**Aspx :**

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxStartDate" AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server" ontextchanged="TextBoxStartDate_TextChanged" Width="150px" Height="16px" ></asp:TextBox>
```

**OutPut :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to give `AutoPostBack="true"` in your textbox definition inoder to trigger the textchange event

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxStartDate" AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server" ontextchanged="TextBoxStartDate_TextChanged" Width="150px" Height="16px" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you may have overwritten or cleared the input box in client side . Have you written any code in client side(using JavaScript) to fill or clear the input box on load ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change value of this TextBox at all, you can do the next thing:

Client side (without `ontextchanged`):

if you are using .NET >= 4.5

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxStartDate" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Width="150px" Height="16px"></asp:TextBox>
```

else

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxStartDate" runat="server" Width="150px" Height="16px"></asp:TextBox>
```

and on server side:

if you are using .NET >= 4.5

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    TextBoxStartDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

else

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    TextBoxStartDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    TextBoxStartDate.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
}
```

---

If you want to control input of TextBox, then server side event is rather expensive step. In this case js is better way

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to solve your problem its simple`using System;

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class demo : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        currentDateTime_textbox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

client side:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="currentDateTime_textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

just do this for showing the date or time in your text box:

```
private void BioChemistry_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    dateTimeTxt.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().ToString();
  }
```

like i'm adding the date time on page load